# Laravel Custom Rule Compare Value with Database

Tags: laravel

I am trying to get a Value from an input text and compare the value input ("Withdrawal") and make sure is less the the wallet balance from the database and if MORE or EQUAL return error. Here is my Code :

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {   
        $this->CurrentUserProfile = User::find(GeneralHelper::GetAuthUserId());  
        $CustomerInfo = Customer_M::Where('User_ID','=',$this->CurrentUserProfile->User_ID)->Get();
        $CustomerWallets = CustomerWallet_M::Where('Cus_ID','=',$CustomerInfo[0]->Cus_ID)->Get();
        $WalletBalanceFromDatabase = $CustomerWallets[0]->CusWalletBalance;

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'WithdrawalAmount' => [
                function($attribute, $value, $fail) use ($WalletBalanceFromDatabase)  {
                    if ($PTransferAmount > $WalletBalanceFromDatabase) {
                        return $fail('You wallet funds is insufficient');
                    }
                },
            ],
        ]);

    }
```

My Problem is i follow exactly from https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures ... and I am still getting  Error : **Object of class Closure could not be converted to string**

Comment: Where are you getting `$PTransferAmount` from?

Comment: Sorry thw PTransferAmount is actually $value

Comment: The Validation part of your snippet is working fine for me. Could you share the entire error stack trace? Perhaps the error is coming from somewhere else, and is not obvious.